# Swift Slamming Logo Animation

Tags: swift, animation

I am creating an application in Swift, and I would like to make an introduction screen that shows off my logo. I want the logo to slam down on the screen, which will then cause a crack, and then that crack slowly grows. I think I can figure out slamming the logo down (by shrinking a UIView of my logo to a certain point), but I am having trouble deciding how to create the crack that will form from slapping down. Do I use views? I am lost.

This is the closest thing that I found to what I would like to do. Sadly, I do not have this software.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bh2y0Xs4IWA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a similar effect before. And to achieve the crack a created multiple images of a growing crack and created an array of images for that screen crack. All you have to do then is animate the images if the imageView.

The other way you can Handel this is to actually draw the crack your self by code which is not difficult really, because in reality it’s just lines and then animate them. But in my experience just using the first method gives a much nicer effect because the images you use can have tons of effects using PS or equivalent.

Comment: If you need any assistance let me know

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go with third party like lottie. In lottie files there some animation you except there, you can also message the designer to help out animation. Its very simple to use in swift.

https://www.lottiefiles.com/

you can also check out my profile:

https://www.lottiefiles.com/parameshvadivel

Lottie animation are done in aftereffects using bodymoving extension and exported as json file to use in xcode.

Comment: Nice animations, I'd rather create them myself though.

Comment: Great, appreciated...:)

Comment: @PvDev . How can i use in swift . i can download the json file ,how to integrate in my project for custom logo

Comment: @UmaMadhavi this link will you to integrate lottie files in xcode https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyL-jp9bFdM

Comment: @PvDev. Thank you . How can i create json for different image or different text same animation https://www.lottiefiles.com/1592-cashchanger-logo

Comment: @UmaMadhavi for cash changer logo link there not providing .ae files(after effects). so you cant change the text or logo.

Comment: @PvDev. Thanks for the reply. How can i achieve such kind of animation

Comment: @UmaMadhavi you can do it by yourself using after effects else you can message designer to design your concept.